Docker base openjdk:17-jdk-slim not taking environment variable
Docker base openjdk:17-jdk-slim not taking environment variable but this issue is not coming with other Docker base openjdk:11-jre-slim.
Can someone explain me the reason.
I am using below command.
docker run  -p 9494:9494-e JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.config.location=/configs/application.properties" -e web.server.uri=http://localhost:8080/  java17-spring-boot-application

